# How to retrieve Metadata stored on file in MongoDB GridFS (VB.net)

Tags: mongodb, vb.net

I can upload file to GridFS system, and store Metadata related to file.

```
 Dim fs As Stream = New FileStream(file, FileMode.Open)

            Dim gridFSBucketOptions As GridFSBucketOptions = New GridFSBucketOptions()
            gridFSBucketOptions.BucketName = "Datamodules"
            Dim bucket = New GridFSBucket(mongoDB, gridFSBucketOptions)
            Dim UploadOptions = New GridFSUploadOptions With {
    .ChunkSizeBytes = 64512,
    .Metadata = New BsonDocument From {
        {"DMC", info.Dmc},
        {"ISSNO", info.Issno},
        {"Inwork", info.Inwork}}
        }
            Dim id As Object = Nothing
            id = bucket.UploadFromStream(Path.GetFileName(file), fs, UploadOptions)
            fs.Close()
```

it creates a new record, looking like

```
_id
6357db2d0120ab34fa67045d
length
31136
chunkSize
64512
uploadDate
2022-10-25T12:48:45.343+00:00
md5
"ada7a4595a04ff20cdae10b383d2cf32"
filename
"DMC-JA-A-00-00-00-00A-005A-A_00101.SGM"

metadata
Object
DMC
"JA-A-00-00-00-00A-005A-A"
ISSNO
"001"
Inwork
"01"
```

this is exactly i want, but i cannot load metadata, i can download file using

```
 bucket.DownloadToStreamByName(_file, fs, downloadOptions)
```

but i cannot access (i dont know how) metadada part, please help. Im using GridFS Component of the Official MongoDB .NET Driver version 2.17.1